# Total factor productivity (TFP) estimation in R via estprod package

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, econometrics, production-function, productivity

good morning
I am trying to calculate the total factor productivity (TFP) for companies in the manufacturing industry through the Levinsohn-Petrin model. To do so, I use the *prodest* package in R. Unfortunately, it does not calculate the coefficient of materials. I am trying with the *estprod* package but I get an error. Could anyone help me please ?
The database is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hdMSM2hF3ThOVkOCMCsqpeDfwh5-yk8x/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112303986520528979371&rtpof=true&sd=true).

```
library(readxl)
library(plm)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(estprod)
library(broom)

data0=read_excel("C:/Users/Greissly/Documents/UIS/Maestria/TESIS/Bases_de_datos/Libro1.xlsx", col_names=T)

names(data0)

PData <- pdata.frame(data0, index = c("ID","Year"))

pdim(PData)

mod1LP = estprod::levinsohn_petrin(data = PData, Y ~ L | C | M, 
                         id = "ID", time = "Year", bootstrap = TRUE, gross = TRUE)
```

The error is the following:

mod1LP = estprod::levinsohn_petrin(data = PData, Y ~ L | C | M, id = "ID", time = "Year", bootstrap = TRUE, gross = TRUE)

Error in if (nrow(index_e1) >= nrow(index_e2)) index_e1 else index_e2 :
argumento tiene longitud cero

Comment: It is advisable to post text as text rather than as image. This helps visually impaired readers, as text can be read out loud while an image cannot. Text can also be copied and pasted on a search engine to look for similar cases and their solutions.